# WordPress menu link doesn't work properly

Tags: functions, theme-development, template-tags

I am developing custom site. The header links work on home-page but  when I go inside shop then the home-link becomes siteurl/shop how to solve this?

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php site_url('home'); ?>">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/shop') ?>">Shop</a>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean this link?

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php site_url('home'); ?>">Homee</a>
```

Then I'm sure it won't work on any other page than home. It's because `site_url()` function doesn't print anything - it returns its value.

And don't print it either. That means, that the link above is empty ;)

You should change it to this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>">Homee</a>
```

PS. Another thing really concerns me in your code. `site_url('home')` - it should be `site_url('/home')` (if your home URL is example.com/home) and `site_url('/')` (if your home URL is example.com/).